# Copy content of word document to another

Tags: vb6, ms-word, copy-paste

How may I copy the content of one word document to another ? It's text only...

I'm opening it like:

```
Dim Word_App     As Word.Application
Dim Word_Doc     As Word.Document

Set Word_App = New Word.Application
Set Word_Doc = Word_App.Documents.Add(DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument)

Word_App.Documents.Open "C:\test.rtf"
```

Ok, I know how to open it. But I need to copy it's content and paste it to a new document... How?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Word_Doc.SaveAs` (once you've set `Word_Doc` properly) and then re-open under a different instance.

More features can be discovered here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840898.aspx